# differentiable function in higher dimensions

Tags: analysis

$f:\mathbb R^{n}\to\mathbb R^{k}$ is a function with $\|f(x)\| \leq \|x\|^{2}$ , $x$ is an element of $\mathbb R^{n}$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.
I already found that $f(0)=0$. I thought  that $f(x)= o(|x|)$ (little o-notation). And f is differentiable in 0 if and only if  there is a linear map A such that $f(x)= f(0) + A(x) + o(|x|)$. So  we take for A the linear map that projects everything on zero. Is this correct or totally wrong?
Thanks

Comment: This is correct. You have proven that your map is differentiable at the origin and that its derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have 
$$
\frac{\|f(x)-f(0)-0\|}{\|x\|}=\frac{\|f(x)\|}{\|x\|}\leq\frac{\|x\|^2\|}{\|x\|}=\|x\|.
$$
This implies that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\|f(x)-f(0)-0\|}{\|x\|}=0,
$$
which says that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$.